# python3.6, difference between async with and await

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.6, python-asyncio

newbie developer coming from python 3.4 here.

my naive understanding is only to use the keyword `async with` when I see that the coroutine is a context manager?

Comment: hiya, sorry I made you feel this way, I did look at the PEP 492 resource and it was a little terse. I'm kinda new and stupid, just wanted to confirm it. thanks :)

Comment: Fair enough. While as a stickler for rules I think your question is off topic for this site, as a person that's been in your general situation, I'm really glad you got the explanation you were looking for. I suppose that means that this will be legitimately useful to future visitors of the site, so close vote retracted.

Comment: thank you for your understanding! I did a quick search and there doesn't seem to be any comparisons between normal and asynchronous context managers, would be nice if someone could have some code examples :)

Comment: @MadPhysicist hey friend how have you been? I got a notification for "nice question badge" today. thank you again for giving this question a chance (I guess our discussion aged well). hope everything is well with you and your family during this tumultuous covid period. cheers :P

Comment: I suppose it did age fairly well. Good job on getting the badge. All's well here. Hope it's the same for you.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From [PEP 492](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/#asynchronous-context-managers-and-async-with):

> A new statement for asynchronous context managers is proposed:
>
> ```
> async with EXPR as VAR:
>     BLOCK
> ```
>
> which is semantically equivalent to:
>
> ```
> mgr = (EXPR)
> aexit = type(mgr).__aexit__
> aenter = type(mgr).__aenter__(mgr)
>
> VAR = await aenter
> try:
>     BLOCK
> except:
>     if not await aexit(mgr, *sys.exc_info()):
>         raise
> else:
>     await aexit(mgr, None, None, None)
> ```

So yes -- it yields into the coroutine returned from the `__aenter__` method of the given context manager, runs your block once it returns, then yields into the `__aexit__` coroutine.